# Writing To Registry Using SID For Permission Instead Of Group Name

Tags: wix, registry, sid

When writing a registry value, is there a way to use the SID instead of the group name?  E.g. currently I have:

```
<Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="{------sanitized------}">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="------sanitized------" ForceCreateOnInstall="yes">
        <Permission User="Users" GenericRead="yes" Read="yes" GenericWrite="yes" />
        <RegistryValue Name="ServerName" Action="write" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes">
            <Permission User="Users" GenericRead="yes" Read="yes" GenericWrite="yes" />
        </RegistryValue>                
    </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

which normally works, but fails in non-English languages, because of the "Users" name being translated.   If I change the Permission elements to the SIDs, it should work (imo) but it does not:

```
<Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="{------sanitized------}">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="------sanitized------" ForceCreateOnInstall="yes">
        <Permission User="S-1-5-32-545" GenericRead="yes" Read="yes" GenericWrite="yes" />
        <RegistryValue Name="ServerName" Action="write" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes">
            <Permission User="S-1-5-32-545" GenericRead="yes" Read="yes" GenericWrite="yes" />
        </RegistryValue>
    </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

Instead it tries to search for a group literally called "S-1-5-32-545". Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do here?  I know other non-wix installers can do this, but there is no information in the wix documentation on such things.

Comment: Sadly no. Supposedly later versions of Windows can do this, but we haven't had the resources to upgrade lately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a very similar problem and could solve it:

- Using `<PermissionEx>` from the Wix Util Extension instead of using
  `<Permission>`.
- Using the built-in custom action
  `WixQueryOsWellKnownSID` to get the localized name of the Users group.

First, you need to add the WixUtilExtension reference to your project.
Then, you need to add the WixUtil namespace to your wxs source file:

```
xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
```

So now you can use the `PermissionEx` element from the Wix Util Extension:

```
<util:PermissionEx User="[WIX_ACCOUNT_USERS]" GenericAll="yes" />
```

To make the property `WIX_ACCOUNT_USERS` available, you need to (implicitly) call the built-in custom action `WixQueryOsWellKnownSID` by adding a property reference to your `<Product>`:

```
<PropertyRef Id="WIX_ACCOUNT_USERS" />
```

This works for me using Wix 3.10 on Windows 10 (English and German)

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a go!

Comment: That solves it!

Wix has some documentation on it here: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/osinfo.html

For future coders, in our .cs files we used: 

`SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(sidType, null);`